# Can we disable the click on any window?

Tags: javascript, php

I have a php page that has a button named "info". On clicking this button Im getting a new window. On appearance of this small window I want to disable all operations or clicks from my 1st window.Is it possible?

My code is:
parent.php:

```
<form method="GET" name="myform" >
<td><input type="radio" name="radioEdit" value="<?php echo $id; ?>"  /><?= $id; ?></td>
<input type="submit" value="info" formaction="edit.php"  onclick="target_popup(myform,'edit.php')"/>
</form>

<script>
    function target_popup(form,page) 
    {
        window.open(page, 'formpopup', 'left=100,top=100,width=600,height=400,menubar,toolbar,resizable');
        form.target = 'formpopup';
    }
</script>
```

edit.php:

```
<?php 
if(isset($_GET['radioEdit']))
{
    $n=$_GET['radioEdit'];
    echo"n=$n";
}
else
{
echo"fail";
?>
```

after clicking on info button this new window appears, can I disable the parent.php until the new window is closed? Please help.

Comment: google `modal window`.

Comment: Hello, you can try twitter bootstrap and use the modal module..

Comment: why not just use lightboxes like [fancybox](http://fancybox.net/) so you'll have only 1 page to control so when this lightbox has been created or instantiated, you can disable the form and when your lightbox has been close it will enable the form again. there's an option for lightboxes that you want in the library I've mentioned.

Comment: @Cedric I dont want to use popups coz that requires installing plugins.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**this is for jquery popups**
a transparent div appear after popup msg shows, and on that div disable all click events there for click events works only on popup window. I think this will be helpful to you :)

```
<div class="disableRightClick">   
</div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/kokilajs/w99Mj/64/

==============================================================

**updated: below code is for window.open(url) popup**

[image]

for check this solution, use server[localhost] without server chrome not work but FF may be work
**parent window**

```
<style type="text/css">
    #disableRightClick{
    position: absolute;
    min-width:100%;
    min-height:100%;    
    background-color:rgba(1,1,1,0.4);
    z-index:99;
    display: none;
    }

    body,html{
        margin:0;
        padding: 0;
    }
</style>
<div id="disableRightClick"></div>

<a href="http://google.com">go to google</a>

<form method="GET" name="myform" >
<td><input type="radio" name="radioEdit" value="<?php echo $id; ?>"  /><?= $id; ?></td>
<input type="submit" value="info" formaction="pop.html"  onclick="target_popup(myform,'pop.html')"/>
</form>

<script>
    var dis = $('#disableRightClick').on("contextmenu",function(e){
        alert('click disabled');
        return false;
    });

    dis.on("click",function(e){
        alert('click disabled');
        return false;
    });

    function target_popup(form,page) 
    {
        var new_window = window.open(page, 'formpopup', 'left=100,top=100,width=600,height=400,menubar,toolbar,resizable');
        form.target = 'formpopup';

        new_window.onload = click_disable;
        function click_disable() {
        window.document.getElementById('disableRightClick').style.display = 'block';
    }    
}
</script>
```

**popup window**(edit.php)

```
popup window test msg
<script>
    window.onbeforeunload = disableparent;
    function disableparent() {
        window.opener.document.getElementById('disableRightClick').style.display = 'none';
    }
</script>
```

Comment: I know that it can be done for popup but my question was to disable for a window :(

Comment: ohhh :) yeh it also possible

Comment: Its coming but. After clicking the close button of edit.php i need to enable access to my parent.php. how can i do that?

Comment: this is screen recode : http://i.imgur.com/XwwEPZU.gif 
if you test put these files to localhost and open it http://localhost/new.html like that

Comment: Currently , On clicking my button I am getting the new window and the 1st window access is disabled. But after clicking the close button I cant access my original window

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/73296/discussion-between-lilly-shk-and-alupotha).

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if it's the most elegant answer, but you could set a variable within your master page, and when this info button is clicked, toggle this variable, and whenever it is toggled, disable all functionality of the page. It won't physically stop users switching back to that window, but it'll stop them being able to use anything until they've done whatever they need in the popup.

Comment: Sorry I dint get u... Can u plz elaborate or give a fiddle?